# Order of importing when overriding variables of Bootstrap 5

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

At [Bootstrap 5 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/customize/sass/) they say:

> Variable overrides must come after our functions, variables, and
> mixins are imported, but before the rest of the imports.

But, at the same time, they provide two examples with variable overrides coming after only their functions, whereas their variables and mixins are imported later.

Here is a copy of the contradictory examples contained in the same document:

```
// Custom.scss
// Option B: Include parts of Bootstrap

// 1. Include functions first (so you can manipulate colors, SVGs, calc, etc)
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// 2. Include any default variable overrides here

// 3. Include remainder of required Bootstrap stylesheets
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// 4. Include any optional Bootstrap components as you like
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";

// 5. Add additional custom code here
```

and

```
// Required
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// Default variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;

// Required
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Bootstrap and its default variables

// Optional Bootstrap components here
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
// etc
```

What would be the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic of Bootstrap is that all variables are declared as `!default`.  (The library does, you shouldn't.)

Normally when you assign a value to a variable, if that variable already had a value, its old value is overwritten.  But with Bootstrap, a Sass library, variables assigned by you will not overwritten if they were not declared `!default`.

See: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/variables#default-values

Generally speaking it does not really matter where you declare your variables as long as CSS is not generated yet - and if you've set variables, they will not be overridden.

Having said that - it's best practice to set yours after `functions` ... but before `root` and the other CSS generation SCSS.

The `$utilities` variable is the exception to that.  If you declare a value to that you'll break the `utilities/api` CSS generation.  Rather manipulate that map with the Utilities API (See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/api/) after you've also imported `variables`, `mixins` & `utilities`.

I suppose, looking at this with a different lens, the Bootstrap authors should be more consistent with their docs, or elaborate on inconsistencies - regardless, drop them an "issue" to let them know: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues

Answer (score 2):

I agree that this is slightly misleading..

> "Variable overrides must come after our functions, variables, and
> mixins are imported, but before the rest of the imports."

This statement is true, *if* you're referencing any of the Bootstrap variables in your overrides. For example...

```
// Required
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Variable overrides (referencing other Bootstrap vars)
$body-bg: $red;
$body-color: $gray-800;

// Optional Bootstrap components here
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
// etc
```

[overrides example referencing Bootstrap vars](https://www.codeply.com/p/88cNHdRdIK)

But the example in the docs is correct (and works) because it's not referencing any Bootstrap variable in the overrides...

```
// Required
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";

// Default variable overrides
$body-bg: #000;
$body-color: #111;

// Required
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

// Bootstrap and its default variables

// Optional Bootstrap components here
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
// etc
```

[overrides example *not* referencing Bootstrap vars](https://codeply.com/p/mTxOcUVLPV)

---

Bootstrap 5 is still in Beta so the docs are still a WIP. Currently there are several open issues relating to variables ([example](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/33263)). As far as the misleading phrase, I would wait for the release version since they're talking about separating base vars from the other vars.